# how do you extract the peak datetime from a data frame given the peak usage per date

Tags: r

I am trying to determine the peak usage hour per day given the max(used) column per server:

```
DATE    DATETIME           Server MACH Capacity Used
9/16/2016   9/16/2016 12:00 cpu1    A   22256   17939
9/16/2016   9/16/2016 13:00 cpu1    A   22256   12591
9/16/2016   9/16/2016 14:00 cpu1    A   22256   15834
9/16/2016   9/16/2016 15:00 cpu2    B   22256   14095
9/16/2016   9/16/2016 16:00 cpu2    B   22256   18186
9/16/2016   9/16/2016 17:00 cpu2    B   22256   12637
```

In this data frame, for date 9/16/2016 for cpu1, max used is 17939 and it happened on 9/16/2016 12:00

I am trying to use the data.table package and can pick the max Used like this:

```
df<-data.table(df)
df<-df[,peak_used:=max(Used), by=c("Server","DATE")]
```

I also need to extract the peak hour and create a new column as peak column and insert the date and time in there?

Any ideas how can I extract the peak DATETIME for max Used for that DATE?

Comment: You can try `df[, peaktime := DATETIME[which.max(Used)], by = .(Server, DATE)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `which.max` to get the index of max rows, after grouping by 'Server', 'DATE', subset the 'DATETIME' using that index, and create the 'peaktime' by assinging (`:=`) the value to it

```
df[, peaktime := DATETIME[which.max(Used)], by = .(Server, DATE)]
```

If we need both 'peakused' and 'peaktime', then

```
df[, c("peakused", "peaktime") := {
       i1 <- which.max(Used)
      .(DATETIME[i1], Used[i1])},  by = .(Server, DATE)]
```

Comment: rather than using which.max, is it possible to use which.quantile, I like to look at the 95th percentile.

Comment: @user1471980  There is no `which.quantile` function.